# Return a delegate through function?

Tags: ios, swift

I am  trying without success, to return a delegate from a UIView class, to another class .

I have a  custom `UIView` subclass I made called **Class1** and inside it I add another custom `UIView` subclass which has a delegate .

**in Class1:**

```
  func setModuleViewFor(index1:Int,index2:Int, delegating:UIView) 
    {
            let tmodule  = ModuleInput(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: self.frame.size.width,height: self.frame.size.height))
            tmodule.setWithData(index1: index1,index2: index2)
            tmodule.delegate= delegating  //********error
            self.addSubview(tmodule)
```

Which gives error saying:

> can not assign value of type UIView to ModuleInputProtocol

Usually, if `ModuleInput` is inside a control view, and I do :

```
 tmodule.delegate= self
```

it works.

Comment: Please edit the question to incorporate the information about the multiple protocols you commented in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must set type of delegating with ModuleInputProtocol

```
func setModuleViewFor(index1:Int,index2:Int, delegating:ModuleInputProtocol) 
        {
                let tmodule  = ModuleInput(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: self.frame.size.width,height: self.frame.size.height))
                tmodule.setWithData(index1: index1,index2: index2)
                tmodule.delegate= delegating  //********error
                self.addSubview(tmodule)
```

and the delegating parameter must realize ModuleInputProtocol when you call setModuleViewFor method

```
add：protocol protocolBase {

}

protocol protocol0:protocolBase {

}

protocol protocol1:protocolBase {

}

protocol protocol2:protocolBase {

}

protocol protocol3:protocolBase {

}

protocol protocol4:protocolBase {

}
```

now you can write you function like this

```
func setModuleViewFor(index1:Int,index2:Int, delegating:protocolBase)
```

My English is very bad, please understand

Comment: Thanks, problem is, it can be one of 5 kinds of delegates this is why I wanted to pass it a view which would get the delegate directly.

Comment: you can weite like this :I have write more in answer